# How to create cartoon images for landing page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a landing page and I would like to incorporate cartoons into it. Something like the one used here : https://www.inscribe.ai . Any ideas on how to create something like this?

Comment: what have you developed so far?

Comment: I would study the source code of that site.

Comment: Create images in .png / .jpg / etc format. Then include them in your page using a html img tag

Comment: @RussJ That site uses images for the cartoons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if you know all of this, but I don't know what you already know. So, I will assume nothing and cover all the basics.

The site you referenced uses jpg/png graphical images, which you are calling *cartoons*. That is what they are, but on the computer they are saved as files that end in `.jpg`, `.png`, etc.

Programs you can use to create such graphics are:

```
Cost   Use For         Program Name
$$$$   Edit Images     Adobe Photoshop
FREE   Edit Images     Gimp
FREE   Edit Images     Paint.net
$$$$   Drawing         Adobe Illustrator
FREE   Drawing         Inkscape
```

*Note that you need skill in art to use these programs. They don't do any of the art work for you - they let you draw lines, circles, boxes, color areas, select areas to color, etc.*

Use one of the above programs to create the image and save it to your computer as a `.jpg` or `.png` file.

Upload the file to your website using a product like FileZilla (or however you get your other files to your website - perhaps through CPANEL or some such). *If using XAMPP or another product that lets you create a webserver on your local computer, just copy the file into the same folder as your .html files*

Finally, include the image on your website using HTML:

```
<img src="the_pic_you_drew.jpg" />
```